# Insert a new full-width buffer underneath two vertically split buffers

Tags: vim, gvim

When having the window split vertically how do I split the window horizontally with a new buffer so that the new buffer ends up on the bottom and takes up the full width of the window:

Start here:

```
|---|---|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
|---|---|
```

End up here:

```
|---|---|
|   |   |
|---|---|
|       |
|-------|
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you opened a third window just focus the window you want at the bottom and press `Ctrl+w J` this will move the window under the other two.

`Ctrl+w K` - move window up

`Ctrl+w L` - move window right

`Ctrl+w H` - move window left

Answer (score 8):

Or, to do it in a single command:

```
:bot sp
```

The long version of this is

```
:botright split
```

But I find that more confusing than the short version! I'll let you look at `:help :botright` for an explanation :-)

Comment: This is perfect but would recommend putting the full commands in for clarity

Comment: Good point. Added.